# How to replace every 2nd specific word in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, replace

I have this list in python:

```
['Banana', 'Apple', 'John', 'Banana', 'Food', 'Banana']
```

And I want to replace every second `Banana` with `Pear` (this should be the result):

```
['Pear', 'Apple', 'John', 'Banana', 'Food', 'Pear']
```

I already have this code:

```
with open('text,txt') as f:
    words = f.read().split()

words_B = [word if word != 'Banana' else 'Pear' for word in words]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension to get all indices of `Banana` and then slicing to get every second of these indices and then just set the corresponding list item to `Pear`:

```
>>> l = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'John', 'Banana', 'Food', 'Banana']
>>> for idx in [idx for idx, name in enumerate(l) if name == 'Banana'][::2]:
...     l[idx] = 'Pear'
>>> l
['Pear', 'Apple', 'John', 'Banana', 'Food', 'Pear']
```

Instead of a comprehension and slicing you could also use a generator expression and `itertools.islice`:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> l = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'John', 'Banana', 'Food', 'Banana']
>>> for idx in islice((idx for idx, name in enumerate(l) if name == 'Banana'), None, None, 2):
...     l[idx] = 'Pear'
>>> l
['Pear', 'Apple', 'John', 'Banana', 'Food', 'Pear']
```

---

Another possibility, specifically if you don't want to change your list in-place, would be creating your own generator function:

```
def replace_every_second(inp, needle, repl):
    cnt = 0
    for item in inp:
        if item == needle:    # is it a match?
            if cnt % 2 == 0:  # is it a second occurence?
                yield repl
            else: 
                yield item
            cnt += 1          # always increase the counter
        else:
            yield item

>>> l = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'John', 'Banana', 'Food', 'Banana']
>>> list(replace_every_second(l, 'Banana', 'Pear'))
['Pear', 'Apple', 'John', 'Banana', 'Food', 'Pear']
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without "special" automatic replace commands?

Comment: @JohnWinston Yep, I added one solution using a generator function. Not sure if that's what you meant but it's working and doesn't replace the original. :)

Comment: @JohnWinston `cnt` just counts the number of times the `item == needle` was True - together with the `cnt % 2 == 0` it is used to find out if it's the "second" occurrence that should be replaced. `yield` is more complicated and already covered (in lots of details) in another [question + answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do).

Answer (score 0):

(Just to point out, your expected result doesn't show you replacing every second `Banana` with `Pear`, it shows you replacing the first and third `Banana`, rather than the second one.  If that really is what you want, you can change the `shouldReplace = False` to `shouldReplace = True` in my following code.)

MSeifert's solutions are slick and were very informative to me as a beginning Python user, but just to point another way to do it changing your list in place would be something like this:

```
def replaceEverySecondInstance(searchWord, replaceWord):
    shouldReplace = False
    for index, word in enumerate(words):
        if word == searchWord:
            if shouldReplace == True:
                words[index] = replaceWord
            shouldReplace = not shouldReplace
```

Running

```
print(words)
replaceEverySecondInstance('Banana', 'Pear')
print(words)
```

Gives the following output:

```
['Banana', 'Apple', 'John', 'Banana', 'Food', 'Banana']
['Banana', 'Apple', 'John', 'Pear', 'Food', 'Banana']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic approach that works by counting down occurances of words since the last replacement:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
r = {
    'Banana': 'Pear',
}

fruits = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'John', 'Banana', 'Food', 'Banana']

def replace(fruits, every, first=True):
  for f in fruits:
    # see if current fruit f should be replaced
    if f in r:
        # count down occurence since last change
        # -- start at 1 if first should be changed otherwise 0
        d.setdefault(f, int(not first))
        d[f] -= 1
        # if we have reached count down, replace
        if d[f] < 0:
            yield r[f]
            d[f] = every - 1 
            continue
    # otherwise append fruit as is
    yield f
```

=> `list(replace(fruits, 2, first=True))`

`['Pear', 'Apple', 'John', 'Banana', 'Food', 'Pear']`

=> `list(replace(fruits, 2, first=False))`

`['Banana', 'Apple', 'John', 'Pear', 'Food', 'Banana']`

Answer (score 0):

A little convoluted but thought I'd throw it out there. You can use a helper function using `itertools.cycle` that alternates between Banana and Pear where an element is Banana or just the original value, eg:

```
from itertools import cycle

data = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'John', 'Banana', 'Food', 'Banana']
b2p = lambda L,c=cycle(['Banana', 'Pear']): next(c) if L == 'Banana' else L
replaced = [b2p(el) for el in data]
# ['Banana', 'Apple', 'John', 'Pear', 'Food', 'Banana']
```